# Why the sudden popularity of .io domains?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

I've noticed a number of new webapps and sites are being hosted at .io domains (the top-level domain for the British Indian Ocean Territories). A couple examples include:

- Forecast.io
- GitHub.io
- Firepad.io

And the list goes on and on.

Is there any particular cause for the sudden popularity of .io domains?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. They're available…
2. …probably because they're significantly more expensive(from any registrar I've ever seen) than the usual TLDs…
3. …and somewhat desirable to techs because of a cheap I/O joke.

The usage itself among web/tech people isn't terribly new. There were several bloggers who started using the TLD years ago that I can't remember at the moment. Over time, it just seems to have slowly built an association with those sorts of people and their output/products. You have to remember that it's gotten really hard to find a decent short domain with .com et al, and *very* few alternative TLDs like .ws have ever gained much traction, so there's a bit of community convergence going on here, stemming in part from that shared joke.

Comment: I understand I/O is for Input/Output but what is the joke?

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's just because most people would not relate `.io` TLDs to British Indian Ocan Territories, but with input/output or whatever abbreviation seems reasonable for the specific domain.

The same thing is happening with `.tv` TLDs, which is for the island of Tuvalu normally, but is more commonly interpreted by people as an abbreviation for "television".

Comment: Actually, the .tv TLD is [specifically being marketed](http://www.watch.tv/)(though not restricted) as such by VeriSign, who have a contract with Tuvalu. The country's so small they wouldn't derive much value from being strict about it anyway. They also did something similar with their phone area code.

Comment: Well, I didn't know about that specific detail, but I did know that indeed Tuvalu approves and gains from this arrangement. I also just read that [GoDaddy recommends not to to buy Tuvalu domains](http://boingboing.net/2009/04/30/godaddy-dont-buy-dot.html) because the island is sinking!